# Am I reinventing the wheel on this idea?

Tags: web-services, gps, wordpress, windows-mobile-gps

Ok here it goes, hope this is an original idea. Scenario is this. I have hosted a personal website, which contains a wordpress blog as well. I have a windows mobile connected to internet via GPRS.

I want to write an application for my windows mobile, which would track my current GPS coordinates (I don't have GPS but have figured out a way to find out the coordinates), and upload them to my site, where I'd provide a web service which can get or set GPS coordinates. Then I want to display my current location in my blog (as a wordpress plugin) or in another page, where it talks with my web service again to obtain my latest GPS coordinates.

So am I reinventing the wheel or there's a complete solution available for me to achieve such a thing?

Any pointers please. It's not directly programming related, but it sure involves programming!!!

Comment: Good God, keep this under wraps before Twitter steals your idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [Google Latitude](http://www.google.com/latitude/intro.html).

Comment: thanks.. it pretty much does what i wanted to do. Now i want to find out how to integrate it in wordpress blog!

Comment: iPhone and iPod touch devices (coming soon) :P

Answer (score 1):

There are quite few of these types of applications/systems.
I myself have written a similar system to try to recover my phone if it gets stolen.
On codeplex you can find [This](http://www.codeplex.com/gpstracker) (not mine).

Comment: thanks, but i'd already seen that tool and that only inspired me to try this idea.